# Необходима библиотека для работы с архивами

Tags: архивация

Добрый день.

Необходима библиотека для работы с архивами: zip, cab jar. Требования следующие:

- работа со списком файлов (содержимым архива)
- чтение данных из избранных файлов архива (без полной разархивации)
- работа со вложенными архивами

Библиотека необходима для написания администраторского скрипта в среде Windows. Доступные языки среды исполнения: PowerShell, VBS, Python.
Посоветуйте, может, кто что-то похожее встречал.

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно библиотеку? 7-Zip можно запускать в пакетном режиме. Если хочется, можно сделать библиотеку из его исходников, благо они доступны.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте 7zip в версии для командной строки. Архивы типа cab только распаковывает. Удовлетворяет как минимум первым двум требованиям (список файлов в архиве и чтение избранных файлов из архива).

Comment: Был еще один проект для .cab - mscab, если не ошибаюсь.